# AVURLAsset getting video size

Tags: xcode, ios5, avurlasset

This is pretty frustrating. I'm trying to get the size of an AVURLasset, but try to avoid `naturalSize` since Xcode tells me, this is deprecated in iOS5.

But: What's the replacement?

I can't find any clue on how to get the video-dimensions without using «naturalsize»...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I just checked the documentation online, and the `naturalSize` method is deprecated for the AVAsset object. However, there should always be an AVAssetTrack which refers to the AVAsset, and the AVAssetTrack has a `naturalSize` method that you can call.

> **naturalSize**
>
> The natural dimensions of the media data referenced by the track. (read-only)
>
> @property(nonatomic, readonly) CGSize naturalSize
>
> **Availability**
>
> Available in iOS 4.0 and later. Declared In AVAssetTrack.h

Via: [AVAssetTrack Reference for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetTrack_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: `nautralSize` is deprecated in iOS 5

Comment: just checked the docs in the link in the answer, and it's not deprecated, it's available in both ObjC and Swift

Comment: there are 2 `naturalSize` in the documentations. `AVURLAsset.naturalSize` is deprecated, but `[[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] naturalSize]` is not

Comment: My answer specifies the `AVAssetTrack` approach, which isn't deprecated and which is what Dave specifies in his second line of code below... It appears I just didn't add the line of code to my answer.

Comment: Sooo everyone switches to doing basically the same thing as what the deprecated method did. Great.

Comment: Do you have any idea to change the resolution of selected video? Should I need to use AVAssetExportPreset1280x720?

Answer (score 54):

Resolution in Swift 3:

```
func resolutionSizeForLocalVideo(url:NSURL) -> CGSize? {
    guard let track = AVAsset(URL: url).tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo).first else { return nil }
    let size = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(track.naturalSize, track.preferredTransform)
    return CGSize(width: fabs(size.width), height: fabs(size.height))
}
```

For Swift 4:

```
func resolutionSizeForLocalVideo(url:NSURL) -> CGSize? {
    guard let track = AVAsset(url: url as URL).tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video).first else { return nil }
    let size = track.naturalSize.applying(track.preferredTransform)
    return CGSize(width: fabs(size.width), height: fabs(size.height))
}
```

Solutions without `preferredTransform` do not return correct values for some videos on the latest devices!

Answer (score 26):

The [deprecation warning on the official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAsset_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html) suggests, "Use the `naturalSize` and `preferredTransform`, as appropriate, of the asset’s video tracks instead (see also [`tracksWithMediaType:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAsset/tracksWithMediaType%3a))."

I changed my code from:

```
CGSize size = [movieAsset naturalSize];
```

to

```
CGSize size = [[[movieAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] naturalSize];
```

It's less pretty and less safe now but won't break when they drop that method.

Answer (score 17):

The deprecation warning says:

```
Use the naturalSize and preferredTransform, as appropriate, 
of the asset’s video tracks instead (see also tracksWithMediaType:).
```

So we need an **AVAssetTrack**, and we want its **naturalSize** and **preferredTransform**. This can be accessed with the following:

```
AVAssetTrack *track = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] firstObject];
CGSize dimensions = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(track.naturalSize, track.preferredTransform);
```

**asset** is obviously your **AVAsset**.

Comment: Hmmm applying the transform as you suggest results in a negative width for me :(

Comment: @Goz Just normalise the dimension components using `fabsf()`.

Answer (score 5):

This is a fairly simple extension for `AVAsset` in **Swift 4** to get the size of the video, if available:

```
extension AVAsset {
    var screenSize: CGSize? {
        if let track = tracks(withMediaType: .video).first {
            let size = __CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(track.naturalSize, track.preferredTransform)
            return CGSize(width: fabs(size.width), height: fabs(size.height))
        } 
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - the app is written in Objective-C, though (I have yet to rewrite it). I'll check it out whether I can adapt your extension...

Comment: Hi I'm facing the same problem did you find a solution ?? because in my case using the natural size + preferredTransform return an obsolete value :( thank you

Answer (score 3):

To derive the dimension of an `AVAsset`, you should calculate the union of all the visual track rects (after applying their corresponding preferred transformation):

```m
CGRect unionRect = CGRectZero;
for (AVAssetTrack *track in [asset tracksWithMediaCharacteristic:AVMediaCharacteristicVisual]) {
    CGRect trackRect = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(CGRectMake(0.f,
                                                             0.f,
                                                             track.naturalSize.width,
                                                             track.naturalSize.height),
                                                  track.preferredTransform);
    unionRect = CGRectUnion(unionRect, trackRect);
}
CGSize naturalSize = unionRect.size;
```

Methods that rely on `CGSizeApplyAffineTransform` fail when your asset contains tracks with non-trivial affine transformation (e.g., 45 degree rotations) or if your asset contains tracks with different origins (e.g., two tracks playing side-by-side with the second track's origin augmented by the width of the first track).

See: `MediaPlayerPrivateAVFoundationCF::sizeChanged()`at https://opensource.apple.com/source/WebCore/WebCore-7536.30.2/platform/graphics/avfoundation/cf/MediaPlayerPrivateAVFoundationCF.cpp

Comment: Altho David, for AVAsset that contains one Video Track, @Avt answer works properly. Right?

Comment: @RoiMulia: I think it's uncommon for assets to have a single video track with non-zero offset. For that, you may unlikely ever see the bug when using that code. Also, I've seen players that ignore the offset when the asset only contains one track. If you care to about handling these edge cases, I recommend experimenting yourself to verify the actual behavior.

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 5

```
let assetSize =  asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0].naturalSize
```

Answer (score 3):

For iOS versions 15.0 and above,

```
extension AVAsset {
    func naturalSize() async -> CGSize? {
        guard let tracks = try? await loadTracks(withMediaType: .video) else { return nil }
        guard let track = tracks.first else { return nil }
        guard let size = try? await track.load(.naturalSize) else { return nil }
        return size
    }
}
```

You can use it like so,

```
Task.init { 
    let videoSize = await videoView.naturalSize() ?? .zero
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in 
        // do your thing 
    } 
}
```

Comment: How to use it from viewDidLoad() ?

Comment: @Md.IkramulMurad, edited original post

Answer (score 1):

**Swift** version of @David_H answer.

```
extension AVAsset {
    func resolutionSizeForLocalVideo() -> CGSize {
        var unionRect = CGRect.zero;
        for track in self.tracks(withMediaCharacteristic: .visual) {
            let trackRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 
            track.naturalSize.width, height: 
            track.naturalSize.height).applying(track.preferredTransform)
            unionRect = unionRect.union(trackRect)
            
        }
        return unionRect.size
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does it return optional?

Comment: It won't return nil as I already set `unionRect` as `CGRect.zero`. I've already edited.