# How use Vuforia?

Tags: ios, iphone, vuforia

Hi I'm trying to develop an iOS app with Vuforia SDK, but where I can find a way to start to integrate this SDK? I looked on the Vuforia web site, but there aren't any interesting documentation about how to integrate the SDK in my app? There's a tutorial that I can follow to understand how it works? On the official web site there are tutorial only for Unity, but I want to develop my app in Objective-C.
I hope you can help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope this link will be helpful for you,  https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/step-2-installing-vuforia-sdk-ios

https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/getting-started-ios-native-sdk

1. Place your unarchived Vuforia sdk in your development
   directory/folder.
2. Add libQCAR.a framework in your project.
3. Set libQCAR.a framework path in XCode build setting "Library Search Paths"
4. Set Vuforia header classes folder path from unarchived Vuforia sdk
   in your development directory/folder in "Header Search Paths"

Comment: Thank you for answer but if you read what the page says, you will easily understand that it's useless guide, because it's says only the structure of the directory you download and it's says nothing about the frameworks I need to import and which directory I've to use in my Xcode project. Don't take this wrong, mine is a review versus Vuforia web site, because there aren't information I need :).

Comment: Could you provide an image or a more specific tutorial how to do this, because I cant find "Other Library Search Path" in Build Settings and I still get the missing <QCar/QCar> error.

Comment: @EridBardhaj, first import libQCAR.a library in your project. Then take that library filepath(directory path) and add it into XCode build setting "Other Library search path".

Comment: I dont see other library search path in XCode 5.0, I just see Library Search Paths, should I put it there?

Answer (score 15):

I realize this is a very old thread, but maybe you'll get an email ping, or perhaps a Google-er will find this useful.

So let me guess, you want to use one of Vuforia's sample apps, but in your own project, right? And you imported everything and made it look just like their project, but it won't even come close to compiling, right? And that sample app is almost certainly the SampleVideo example? If so, read on…

1) Xcode *will* get the import wrong if you simply include the library in your project. What you want to do is…

a) make a copy of the build folder inside the Vuforia API and put it somewhere else

b) rename that to something more useful, like "Vuforia"

c) use Add… to put that new folder into your own project (you can refer to it, I copy)

d) go to Build Settings, type "search" into the search bar (seems redundant, I know)

e) you should now see two very important lines, Header Search Paths and Library Search Paths. if you don't, you need to find them

f) double-click on header search paths so the pop-up gizmo appears. press the + button. Now go into the finder, find the Vuforia/include folder (which might be inside your own project if you copied it, like I do) and drag that folder into the pop-up gizmo

g) repeat for the Library, but drag the lib folder in instead.

**Ok, done!** No, sorry, I lied…

2) import the code from their samples that you want. It might be in several different folders

3) go to Build Phases and while that screen is up, do a build.

4) lots of errors will appear about ARC. use the search bar to find those files and add a "-fno-objc-arc" flag to each one. Repeat as required.

5) do another build, note that you're missing libraries which Vuforia couldn't be bothered to tell you about (*sigh*). So in Build Phases, open Link Binary With and add…

a) AVFoundation
b) AudioToolbox
c) QuartzCore
d) CoreMedia
e) CoreVideo
f) MediaPlayer
g) OpenGLES
h) CoreMotion
i) SystemConfiguration

6) do another build. Now you'll get a different error, but it won't be obvious it's different until you click on it. Look for "missing required architecture". If you see this, change your target to your phone, because Vuforia doesn't work in the simulator. Which makes sense because it doesn't have a camera… or not, because my apps do a lot more than just Vuforia but this limitation means I can't test any of it on the sim. (*sigh*)

7) so you switch the target to your shiny new iPhone 5S, build and… get errors about missing architectures. So now you see it's missing arm64… so you have to go to your Build Settings, remove Standard Architectures and add in armv7 and armv7s.

8) now you can look at the warnings and go about fixing the errors in their code, and the long-ago deprecated calls. naturalSize is easy:

[AVURLAsset getting video size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433774/avurlasset-getting-video-size)

One last warning. Once you get everything compiling and such, you'll try to import one of the Vuforia headers into your own code and then you'll get another error about "namespace". Make sure to change any file that imports from their code to a .mm as well.

Are you having fun yet?

Comment: OMG I forgot one, CoreMotion.

Comment: Thanks for the guide...much better than what the Vuforia site has. That being said I'm still getting "Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:". In build settings I have Architectures: armv7 armv7s...Build Active Architecuture Only: NO...Valid Architectures: armv7 armv7s.

Comment: They 1&0, I just came across your post. That is an odd error, are you trying to run it in the emulator or on your iDevice. Note that they don't include code for the emulator, so all debugging has to take place on a physical device - one more charm of the platform!

Answer (score 3):

Today Vuforia 4.0 is simple. There is no need to "Add libQCAR.a framework in your project." and so on.

Take care of the path of folder in this image!!!

[image]

Step by step:

1. https://developer.vuforia.com/library/articles/Solution/Installing-the-Vuforia-iOS-SDK
2. https://developer.vuforia.com/library/articles/Solution/Installing-the-Vuforia-iOS-Samples
3. https://developer.vuforia.com/library/articles/Solution/Compiling-and-Running-a-Vuforia-iOS-Sample-App

Comment: This is the correct answer for the version 5.0.6. Thanks for compiling those resources for me!

Comment: These steps listed (1-3) are very limiting in their description as there is no step-by-step process for adding Vuforia to your own app. The Vuforia documentation is terrible. @Anders - did you get Vuforia 5.0.6 working in your own app or did you use the Vuforia samples app?

Comment: @Silverstar I actually switched to Wikitude :D

Comment: Indeed, Vuforia is massively complex and undocumented.  They have object references, but it's very hard to use.  I'm switching to Wikitude as well.

Answer (score 2):

For Vuforia 4.0 (currently in beta), Maury's answer didn't quite do it for me. I kept getting errors about "missing required architecture armv7s", even though I had set Architectures to armv7 / armv7s.

I then also to also change:

- C++ Language Dialect in Build Settings to: C++ 11
- C++ Standard Library in Build Settings to: libc++

After making the above changes my project built successfully.

Comment: Complete (???) instructions here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28562352/vuforia-videoplayback-example-for-4-0