# Get dimensions of a video asset

Tags: ios, iphone, gpuimage

How can I get dimesions of a movie from iPhone gallery.

I have it loaded by using GPUImage:

```
movieFile = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:_assetURL];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the call

> movieFile = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:_assetURL];

The movieFile is simply a holder of the URL for now, so you can't access the dimensions. When processing an AVAsset will be created.

If you just want the dimensions, I would create my own AVAsset from the URL, and then get the dimensions as mentioned in this post:[AVURLAsset getting video size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433774/avurlasset-getting-video-size)