# Get bandwidth of stream from m3u stream

Tags: ios, avplayer

I'm using AVURAsset with a HLS url. The response is like below

```
    QualityLevels(1020000)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl)
    #EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-   INF:BANDWIDTH=1189576,RESOLUTION=668x376,CODECS="avc1.4d401f",URI="QualityLevels(1020000)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl,type=keyframes)"
    #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1810952,RESOLUTION=924x520,CODECS="avc1.4d401f,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="audio"


   QualityLevels(1628000)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl)
   #EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1810952,RESOLUTION=924x520,CODECS="avc1.4d401f",URI="QualityLevels(1628000)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl,type=keyframes)"
   #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=2803314,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.640029,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="audio"
```

Can I get the metadata from this playlist file with AVFoundation class, like bandwidth, resolution?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the resolution of video as its natural size as following [AVURLAsset getting video size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433774/avurlasset-getting-video-size)

Regarding bandwidth, it is probably bit-rate of video. You can try this implementation

```
- (int)getBandwidth:(AVPlayer *)moviePlayer {
    VPlayerItemAccessLog *log = [moviePlayer.currentItem accessLog];
    NSArray *events = [log events];
    AVPlayerItemAccessLogEvent *event = [events lastObject];
    return ((int) ceilf(event.indicatedBitrate / 1000.0));
}
```

I hope this would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to get all bandwidth. This method seems only can get current track required speed.